# How can I measure the frequency of vibration of a surface/object?

Tags: frequency, measurements, home-experiment, vibrations

I'd like to know if there is a solution that allows me to measure the frequency of vibration of a surface/object. Primarily I am seeking to improve my speaker/home audio setup. The vibrometers I've found (and can afford) can give me the amplitude of vibration, speed of vibration and acceleration of vibration. I want to be able to measure what frequencies an object is vibrating at, though. If anyone could help me out, either by pointing me towards tools that can meet my needs, or letting me know how to derive the frequency from other data, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy and cheaper way to do this is with a *microphone* (basically an uncalibrated vibration sensor!) and an oscilloscope, upon which you display the microphone output. The frequency of vibration can be extracted from the oscilloscope display by measuring the time between peaks of the waveform; the inverse of that time is the frequency of the vibration.

Answer (score 0):

If the devices can measure acceleration, then you can calculate frequency from it. The time interval between the membrane‘s change of direction of motion is related to the time interval between the change of sign of acceleration. For a pure note, the two are the same.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. The store also says there's viewing software included so that may be helpful.